# How do I know the level of a monster, creature, or human in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I know the level of a monster creature or human in Skyrim?

Comment: It doesn't help you yet, but I suspect a lot more concrete info on the level ranges of monsters and humanoids will be available once the Creation Kit is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only do this on the PC via the console:

1. Open the console with `~`
2. Click on the target (now you should see the ID of the target in the form of a hex string)
3. Type `getlevel`

You can also just use `getlevel [hexstring]` if you know the ID of what you want to check.

Comment: It's also possible to triangulate to varying degrees of confidence using an assortment of illusion spells, poisons, and quick saves.

Comment: What about for someone playing on console? Could he have at least a range of confidence he could go off of? Are some mobs stuck to certain level ranges?

Comment: @andy your only option as a console player is to either triangulate, as I note in my comment, or to check the UESP or official strategy guide.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I'm sure that's exactly what Bethesda expected you to do to figure out if your level-based spells would work against an enemy :)

Comment: Kidding apart, I'm surprised there isn't an in-game perk or spell that allows you to see enemy levels - that way you'd *know* if your spell/staff that made monsters under level X flee/whatever would work or not!

Comment: @Alex That would break realism. Having level requirements on spells  does too which I don't think they should. Honestly spells should work on all level creatures just have a much greater chance of failure on higher level opponents. Although that argument leaves the scope of this discussion. A spell to see the level of enemies removes the layer of realism by adding in obvious meta-game elements to the enemies you fight.

Comment: @izuriel I agree - I was speaking mainly on the basis that Skyrim *does* have staves/spells that only work on "level X and below" monsters. I'd much rather have a uniform skill/probability based approach. "I got an awesomesauce staff of +10 Flee? Great, I have no idea how to use it, just like this Bow of +10 Flee. I will sell them both."

Comment: @izuriel What about a spell that simply made the soul you can trap appear giving you a general indication of their 'level' by how big of a soul they have.. and letting you check your gems to see if you can hold it.

Comment: @James soul sizes have only a loose correlation with creature level.

Comment: @yx I was just thinking that sort of thing could be used where it would not really break immersion. Its still interpreted data sort of deal, size plus colour maybe or the like... Might be a fun mod to try and make for the game really...  I just have to stop spending 20-30 hours exploring every little house I run into and finish the game first.

Comment: @Alex I addressed the issue with items displaying mob level requirements in my comment.

Comment: @James That would be like the spell that allows you to see people through walls by covering them in purple fog (I'm thinking Oblivion, I don't use spells so I haven't seen it in Skyrim), which is a perfectly acceptable solution. You see an "aura" of power, not a number level number.